# Extract substring from a string using awk

Tags: regex, string, bash, shell, awk

I have string which can be one of the following two formats :

```
dts12931212112 : some random message1 : abc, xyz
nodts : some random message2
```

I need to extract substring from these two string which doesn't have 'dts' part i.e. it should return :

```
some random message1 : abc, xyz
some random message2
```

I need to do this inside a bash script.

Can you help me with the awk command, which does this operation for both kind of strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through awk's gsub function.

```
$ awk '{gsub(/^[^:]*dts[^:]*:|:[^:]*dts[^:]*/, "")}1' file
 some random message1 : abc, xyz
 some random message2
$ awk '{gsub(/^[^:]*dts[^:]*:[[:blank:]]*|:[^:]*dts[^:]*/, "")}1' file
some random message1 : abc, xyz
some random message2
```

You could apply the same regex in sed also, but you need to enable `-r` `--regexp-extended` parameter.

`^` asserts that we are at the start. `[^:]*` negated character class which matches any character but not of `:`, zero or more times. So this `^[^:]*dts[^:]*:` would match the substring at the start which contain `dts`. It it won't touch if the substring is present at the middle. This `:[^:]*dts[^:]*` pattern matches  the middle or last substring which has `dts`. Finally replacing the matched chars with an empty string will give you the desired output.

**Update:**

```
$ awk '{gsub(/^[^[:space:]]*dts[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]:]*|[[:space:]:]*[^[:space:]]*dts[^[:space:]]*/, "")}1' file
some random message1 : abc, xyz
some random message2
```

Comment: I forgot to mention - consider any white space as separator after dts number (colon ':' may or may not be present ) . In that case this command doesn't work .

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Btw is there any difference in awk in using [:blank:] and [:space:]?

Comment: you could use `[[:blank:]]` also instead of `[[:space:]]` where `blank` matches any horizontal white space character( whitespace,tab) where `space` matches both horizontal and vertical whitespace character (space,tab,newline,carriage return).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `awk`

```
awk -F" : " '{$1="";sub(FS,"")}1' OFS=" : " file
some random message1 : abc, xyz
some random message2
```

Just remove first field when separated by `:`

---

Another version:

```
awk -F" : " '{print substr($0,index($0,$2))}' file
some random message1 : abc, xyz
some random message2
```

Get all data from second field and out separated by `:`